# How can I retrieve the default style of enumerate environment?

Tags: listings, enumerate, itemize

When I use nested `enumerate` environment it gave this style:

1.

(1)

(1)

I want to know, how to restore the default style?

I put the whole code in case one of the used packages are the cause.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt,oneside,authoryear]{extreport}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1256,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ arabic ,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault} 
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{pplx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Validation.
\item Static.
\item Dynamic.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Linear.
\item Non-Linear.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not standard. Without a M.W.E., I'm afraid we can't help…

Comment: @Bernard - The problem is almost solved by Ambika, but I don't like to do that for every time I use `enumerate`, so is there any way to restet the `enumerate` to its default settings?

Comment: What I need to know is the code that produces this style. We can do almost anything we want with `enumitem`, but If I don't  know *how* you obtained this result, what can  I do?

Comment: @Bernard-  I edit the question and add the M.W.E .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is linked to the `arabic` option of `babel`. I  solved it (at least for the `english` part of the text) replacing the `enumerate` package with `enumitem` and setting the labels for the different levels of enumerate (up to level 3) in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt,oneside,authoryear]{extreport}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%cp1256,
\usepackage[arabic , main = english]{babel}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{pplx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 1] {label = \arabic*.} %
\setlist[enumerate, 2] {label = (\alph*)} %
\setlist[enumerate, 3] {label = (\roman*)} %
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Validation.
  \item Static.
  \item Dynamic.
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item Linear.
          \item Non-Linear.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution, is trying to redefine to its original style with a customization as follows (by specifying the style needed as an option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item First level
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Second level
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Third level
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item Fourth level
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is possible, can you define it at the beginning of the documents? i.e. resetting the environment of `enumerate` .